# Error Date in SQL Query

Tags: sql, date, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a problem with my SQL query.

The error is :

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a smalldatetime data type resulted in an" + " out-of-range value.

I tried to use the `CONVERT` function to remedy it but in vain.

```
public static List<string> Helper_Statistic_6(DateTime start, DateTime end) {
        DateTime dateStart = start;
        DateTime dateEnd = end;

        string query = "SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE DATE BETWEEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),'" + dateStart+ "',120) and CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),'" + dateEnd+ "',120) ";
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is SQL Server?

Comment: What database-management program are you using?

Comment: Can you give an example with values that are being used?

Comment: Check your use of single-quote marks... are those fields `varchar`, or are they being cast as text by the use of quote marks?

Comment: Sorry, it's Sql Server 2008 R2
Example of date in my rows : 2002-12-30 00:00:00 (type smalldatetime)
When i use this query in Sql Server : 
L.DO_DATE BETWEEN '01/01/2014' and '03/31/2014' 
it's works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you're using C# with Microsoft SQL Server.

In any case, to avoid the woes of code injection, one should try to use parametized SQL. Allow the compiler take care of marshalling a C# Date to a SQL Date.

EDIT: As per @marc_s suggestion, you should beware using reserved SQL keywords as column names, otherwise, protect them from being treated as SQL keywords by using [ ] symbols, i.e. `[DATE]` isntead of `DATE`.

I would expect the syntax to look like this:

```
public static void Run_Helper_Statistic_6(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
        "SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE [DATE] BETWEEN @start and @end", connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("start", start));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("end", end));
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, be aware that `DATE` is a **keyword** in SQL and thus makes a really bad column name - if that's really the name, it has to be put into square brackets: `... WHERE [Date] BETWEEN ....` - or better yet - avoid those keywords as column names!

Comment: I changed as you said Stephen Quan and now when I want to get the value of the reader, I have a cast problem between DateTime and String. to get the value, I do this :  stat6.Date = DateTime.Parse(reader.GetString(0));

Comment: I'm tired I think I just had to change in reader.getDateTime.